# SSIS OLEDB exports more records than SQL query

Tags: oracle, ssis, oracle-sqldeveloper, etl, oledb

I have an SSIS package in which I created a data flow task where the OLE DB source, data coversion, and Excel destination are there. Command that I used in OLE BD source gives me 19024 records whereas when I run the same query in SQL developer I get 204 rows. Can anyone please guide me on what is happening?

Comment: What is the command you are executing? Can you provide screenshots of both queries (showing the sql command)?

Comment: I assumed that you are importing data from Oracle (since you mentioned SQL Developer)

Comment: yes I am fetching data from oracle and need to export it to excel file.

Comment: i will share the query screen shot in a while, but it is same query, I ran the query in SQL developer and then copy pasted in it OLE DB table command

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend creating a view or Stored Procedure in the Oracle database with the logic required to return precise records needed.

Use the new view or SP as a source for your OLEDB source then add a row count component between your OLEDB component and Data Conversion component to see in runtime how many rows are you retrieving.

Also, if you want to make sure your data conversion is sending the same count of rows add an extra row count between your Data Conversion component and Excel Destination.

I'm assuming you are handling the excel file creation out of your SSIS package because if you are not recycling the file you will append the results to prior records in there, producing a feeling that you are receiving more rows than expected.